# cannot get updates / drivers on new windows 7 installation

Tags: windows-7, windows, drivers

I have just installed a new copy of Windows 7 Pro, but without any drivers.

The first thing I tried to install was the ethernet controller driver, but I could not find out what driver to actually install. With the help of 3rd party software, I managed to find out the vendor and installed the driver (downloaded from a different PC). However I only got internet connection for the 1st couple of seconds, then I wasn't able to connect.

After a few reboots I finally had a stable connection (could access websites) but doing windows updates or downloading rest of the drivers through device management showed no progress.

I have no idea what else I could do in this case.. never happened to me before. 
I've read that it can also be somehow related to faulty hardware ?

/edit: 
Still the same thing happening. I can access the internet, but can't get any windows updates or driver updates...

Comment: Order to install drivers in general, Chipset, Video, Network, Sound, then any other you need.  After you get drivers installed properly, See my answer here concerning Windows Updates.  http://superuser.com/a/1022204/40928

Comment: Post the make and model of your PC, if it is custom built, post the model and revision of the motherboard.

Comment: Does Windows update give you any error message?

Comment: Not at all. Just 'updates are being searched for' (just a vague translation from German). The same with any automatic driver installation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you may have the incorrect driver for your network connection causing various other issues.

My preferred way to identify the components in your machine, and their relevant drivers, is to do the following. Note, you **will** need a machine that can connect to the internet and a way to transfer at least a network driver.

Usually, I will start with either the Wireless or Ethernet driver, to make the rest of the process a lot simpler.

1. Open Device Manager. The quickest way to do this on Windows 7 is to press <kbd>Win</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd>, and type `mmc devmgmt.msc`
2. Your devices will likely be listed as `Unknown Device`, `Other device` or possibly within their relevant categories but without a driver. Look for anything labelled `Ethernet controller` or `Network controller`. If not, it may simply be `Unknown device`. At this stage, it's hard to know.
   [image: Device Manager]
3. Double click one of these. Go to the `Details` tab.
4. In the dropdown box, choose `Hardware Ids`
5. For most devices, you should get a similar screen to this:
   [image: Hardware IDs]
6. The important parts here, using my wireless as an example, are the `VEN_8086` and `DEV_08B3` parts. These are used to identify my exact device, using the `Vendor ID` and `Device ID`. In this instance, `VEN_8086` is always an Intel device. We're a step closer. The next part, `DEV_08B3` is the exact device by this vendor.
7. From here, a simple search online on our internet enabled device, for `VEN_8086 DEV_08B3`, will almost always reveal exactly what device I have, especially for such a well known vendor as Intel. [Google search result](https://www.google.com.kh/search?q=VEN_8086+DEV_08B3&oq=VEN_8086+DEV_08B3&aqs=chrome..69i57j0.694j0j7&sourceid=chrome&es_sm=93&ie=UTF-8).
8. You will see when searching this that `Intel(R) Dual Band Wireless-AC 3160` comes up a lot. So my next [Google Search](https://www.google.com.kh/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=Intel(R)+Dual+Band+Wireless-AC+3160+driver+Windows+7) is for `Intel(R) Dual Band Wireless-AC 3160 Windows 7 Driver`. First link is on Intel's page, exactly what I want to see.
9. I'd then get the driver, transfer it by USB stick or equivalent to my machine without drivers. I'd then install the driver and connect to my network.
10. From here it's a case of repeating those steps for each device, until all drivers have their latest versions installed.

Now, this won't work for some obscure devices quite so easily (although it often helps identify those obscure devices you'd otherwise have no idea about). Also if it's a machine from an OEM, there may be certain devices that only work correctly with a download from the OEM's website. There can also be custom drivers for various ACPI components, custom buttons etc. that will only be found here. Additionally, some USB devices won't be as easy to identify, and won't necessarily have a `VEN` and `DEV` id. Instead, you'll get a `VID` and `PID`, which can still give some information when looked up.

These are the steps I use almost every time I reinstall an OS. Hope it is of some use to you.

Comment: thanks. I knew this was possible at the back of my head, but didn't actually get to it. Will try on Monday and update the question accordingly.

Comment: so just an update.. turned out, I did have the right ethernet driver.  But the problem persists... I've updated the question. No idea what to do now.

Answer (score -1):

When you buy a new PC or just format it, remember to download the driver: THIS IS THE FIRST ACTION TO DO.
Now, download from another PC Speccy or Cpu-z and with the correct hardware model, search the correct driver (Remember the difference beetween 32 & 64 bit).

Else, install just Ethernet/Wireless driver and use a software like Driver Booster to "Auto-Download" the correct driver (This is not my favorite way...)

Sorry for my BAD English, i'm trying to learn.
Enjoy

Comment: This does not really answer the author's question.  It also is sort of obvious.  *The question is about Windows Update and how to resolve the behavior described.*

Answer (score -2):

To be able to get you the drivers you need you need to know the make and model of the computer or the motherboard and graphics card model if its a custom built pc.

Comment: This does not really answer the author's question and honestly is sort of obvious that in order to download drivers you need to know which drivers to download.  *The question is about Windows Update and how to resolve the behavior described.*

Comment: If it was obvious to the author how to find the drivers they would have done it already... using the built-in windows find drivers thing does not work. You need to just use google and lookup drivers using the information I was asking for.

Comment: *Which is the reason I indicate you should clarify the process within your answer*