# Windows 7 update stuck

Tags: windows-7, networking, windows-update, windows-10-upgrade

There seems to be some sort of a network issue that is preventing Windows Update from downloading updates. The progress bar keeps on going forever.

I have done just about everything on the PC to make it work to no avail. This includes disabling firewalls and anti-virus software. According to this post which I believe sums up my situation there might be an issue with my Internet connection:

http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-update/windows-7-checking-for-updates-stuck-forever/cf0aefb1-477c-41df-a330-130383581c6d?auth=1

I am connected through a wireless Cisco router. Unfortunately I don't have access to another network. Neither do I have a network cable. But my Internet is working; I can download and upload files no problem.

The OS is not new but the user I'm logged in as is a new admin user.

How can I know what's wrong with my Internet connection, or more precisely what's blocking Windows Update?

P.S. One of the ideas I tried was upgrading the OS to Windows 10, but even the Windows 10 Installer gets stuck at the "Getting Updates" screen.

P.S. I am not able to connect my computers at home even though they are all in the same workgroup. The PC shows up as a shared computer on a Mac but is not connectable. All computers are connected wirelessly through the aforementioned router.

Comment: define forever, how long did you wait?

Comment: A whole night..

Comment: Common issue in W7, see my suggestions here...http://superuser.com/questions/951960/windows-7-sp1-windows-update-stuck-checking-for-updates/1022204#1022204

Comment: I gave your suggestion a try with open arms, and it worked!! Glad to be moving away from Windows.