# What is Windows Update doing? Behavior issues

Tags: windows-7, windows-update

I'd like to understand better what Windows Update process is doing.
In some computer, I cannot understand if it is blocked or it is working fine.

I used to have hands on keyboards of friends and relatives. And various errors. So, a fix, a cleanup. Usually problem is solved.

Last one:
Windows 7 Ultimate N (64 bit)
Sp 1.
Processor: AMD Phenom II X6 1075T @3 GHZ
Ram: 8 GB

**Last success update:** in the summer 2015, cannot remember exactly.

After some errors and some fix I tried almost everything described here:
[Windows 7 SP1 Windows Update stuck checking for updates](https://superuser.com/questions/951960/windows-7-sp1-windows-update-stuck-checking-for-updates)

Then I renamed the following directories:

```
C:\Windows\System32\catroot2
C:\Windows\SoftwareDistribution
```

And the file:

```
C:\Windows\WindowsUpdate.log
```

Just to have a clean start.

Then started relative services and forced: **Check updates** from control panel.

It started to populate the directories mentioned above and write the log file. I was waiting.

It seems to work until 12:14. Last line wrote in the log file is:

```
2016-01-19  12:14:57:286     452    f98 DtaStor WARNING: Attempted to add URL http://download.windowsupdate.com/d/msdownload/update/others/2016/01/19855795_9dd5f59725a2a2b101788de29b84ed6289c00c5b.cab for file ndX1lyWiorEBeI3im4TtYonADFs= when file has not been previously added to the datastore2016-01-19   12:14:57:286     452    f98 DtaStor WARNING: Attempted to add URL http://download.windowsupdate.com/d/msdownload/update/others/2016/01/19855795_9dd5f59725a2a2b101788de29b84ed6289c00c5b.cab for file ndX1lyWiorEBeI3im4TtYonADFs= when file has not been previously added to the datastore
```

Then nothing. Meanwhile a process is working. **Svchost.exe -k netsvc**

It was eating about 20% of CPU power (it is an esacore) and about 1.2 GB of memory.

I had no other activity I could understand until 12:41:48.

Then, a new line was in the log:

```
2016-01-19  12:41:48:434     452    f98 Agent     * Added update {4F9AF231-5723-4A52-9293-015D4E5D4CDF}.103 to search result
```

In the middle nothing I could see. Nothing in the eventviewer and no message on screen. Then it restarted to write in the log, and I was finally able to select and install updates.

**What was it doing in the middle?**

I have another similar computer to fix. But it is a not powerful laptop. An hp that becomes hot and hotter. I'd like to understand if I have a problem or I just need it to work for hours.

Comment: See my post here to alleviate this issue....http://superuser.com/a/1022204

Comment: Thank you. I will try on the laptop this night. But the question still is: how can I understand what is it doing? I can't find any good document that explayn process in details. Or any log..

Comment: capture a xperf trace and I can tell you what it does: http://pastebin.com/LCP8HgPy

Comment: have you captured the trace so that I can see what WU is doing?