# Rogue SVHOST process

Tags: windows-7, process, memory-leaks

How might I go about diagnosing the cause of a svhost process that consumes vast amounts of RAM and CPU on a Windows 7 system? It appears apparently randomly, it can be terminated without any problems, but can often pop up a few minutes later (or several hours). It apparently does nothing useful: certainly nothing essential. System scans for viruses have turned up nothing.

I've lived with this inconvenience for a few months now, but a cure, or the means by which a cure could be arrived at, would be great.

[image]

The massive drops in the CPU (green) and RAM (blue) are associated with the killing of the process tree.

I sometimes notice flickering and graphical changes in windows briefly after terminating the svhost process.

**UPDATE:**

After the advice of Moab I waited until the svhost reappeared and took a screenshot of its processes (non-highlighted are irrelevant if I'm reading it correctly). Interestingly they all seem to be network based. Perhaps Windows Update is the root of the problem?

[image: svhost processes]

Comment: Task Manager can find it, open task manager>procesess tab, right click on the svchost entry that uses too much memory and select "go to services", this will will highlight process running under that instance of svchost, this will narrow the process that is causing the issue.

Comment: tgis is the WindowsUpdate service. install this update: http://superuser.com/a/996072/174557 or the newest one from March: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/3138612

Comment: it is WU as I already told you. Install one of the linked WU CLient Updates.

Comment: @magicandre1981 Hi, thanks for the advice. Tried that (download, succesful install + restart). Svhost still coming back

Comment: capture a xperf trace of the memory usage: http://pastebin.com/yLvYak6n

Comment: have you captured the trace?