# Windows Update Isn't Working and C++ 2015 Is Hanging

Tags: windows-7, windows, installation

I did a fresh Windows 7 install and I installed XAMPP.  After that, I realized I needed to install C++ 2015.  But I couldn't install until I installed SP1.  After I installed SP1, I've had some issues.  When I go to search for more updates, it keeps searching for updates for hours.  And when I go to install C++ 2015 it gets hung at windows7_msu_x64.

My Windows update:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/6Fqc5.png]

And when Windows is searching for updates, I can't install C++ because it says another install is happening.

I honestly have no clue what is happening.

Comment: Is this a Windows 7 SP1?

Comment: Please check this answer: http://superuser.com/questions/951960/windows-7-sp1-windows-update-stuck-checking-for-updates
Try this 'fixit' if the pc is also hanging: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2700567