# Win7 slow down randomly

Tags: windows-7

After installing Win 7 Service Pack 1 and IE 11 the hard disk light is continuously ON and Win 7 slows down considerably, in the resource monitor MsMpEng.exe, svchost.exe (...) show very high number of hard faults, then I manually stop all these processes and 5-10 minutes after doing that the OS is back to normal, what is the cause and remedy for this?

Update:  This happens only when I go online with chrome or opera and open multiple tabs, if I am not surfing the web then everything is fine.  The svchost.exe(netsvcs) is the biggest memory hogger.

Comment: Uninstall the Microsoft antivirus. Try some other antivirus.

Comment: MSe is crap, try a different one

Comment: @magicandre1981, if you are saying MS internet explorer then I am not using it, I am using chrome, I needed IE tab in chrome extension for that I installed IE 11 and for that I had to install service pack 1

Comment: no, I talk about Microsoft Security Essentials (MSE - MsMpEng.exe). Uninstall it and use a different AV suite. For the svchost.exe(netsvcs) issue, this is WU related. Se my solution here: http://superuser.com/a/996072/174557

Answer (score 0):

That behavior can be caused by a virus or a specific KB patch.

If a virus is usually detectable and can be removed by anti-virus software, in the case of a KB it can be very complicated to determine which KB is at fault.
For that, you must determine exactly what process keeps the CPU/HDD usage high, determine if it can be permanently terminated and denied at startup and if is needed at startup, you must find the exact patch that generated the problem by analyzing that process in detail with specific software like process explorer.