# explorer.exe ntdll.dll c0000005 failure when log in

Tags: windows-7, windows-explorer

I have my `explorer.exe` crashed, with faulting module `ntdll.dll`, error code `c0000005` fail when i attempted to logon, nothing including desktop and task-bar is shown up, help me please, i already removed the newly upgraded avast but still no hope.
dump : [https://www.sendspace.com/filegroup/2nWPKS5%2FdjL1U0xPXQJn9giPp4iTuOBI4IGA%2BrW9tq%2FipHNb06VV%2BBVYAVHW9dHU5hlG21Pb%2F2VOKZkOW8X92Q]

Comment: If you boot into a minimal configuration does this error still happen?

Comment: problem still exist in safe mode

Comment: look if you can generate a crash dump: http://pastebin.com/WACz5GBU try to Open taskmgr, here run regedit.exe and try to import the reg file here

Comment: i already have the dump, i will post it here

Comment: note that i can still open programs with the `new process` button in task manager, but some including `notepad` and `cleanmgr` will show ntdll wrror

Comment: https://www.sendspace.com/filegroup/2nWPKS5%2FdjL1U0xPXQJn9giPp4iTuOBI4IGA%2BrW9tq%2FipHNb06VV%2BBVYAVHW9dHU5hlG21Pb%2F2VOKZkOW8X92Q

Comment: I posted an answer. TSVN 1.9.2 causes it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Looking at the crashdump with Windbg.exe](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/Windows/Hardware/ff538058(v=vs.85).aspx) (which is part of the Debugging Tool for windows/Windows SDK) shows that TortoiseSVN 1.9.2 causes the crash:

```
*******************************************************************************
*                                                                             *
*                        Exception Analysis                                   *
*                                                                             *
*******************************************************************************

*** ERROR: Symbol file could not be found.  Defaulted to export symbols for TortoiseOverlays.dll - 

DUMP_CLASS: 2

DUMP_QUALIFIER: 400

CONTEXT:  (.ecxr)
eax=00000001 ebx=00000001 ecx=0034cd60 edx=0000ffff esi=ffffffff edi=00360032
eip=7705bef6 esp=0017e0c8 ebp=0017e0d4 iopl=0         nv up ei ng nz na pe nc
cs=001b  ss=0023  ds=0023  es=0023  fs=003b  gs=0000             efl=00010286
ntdll!LdrpUpdateLoadCount2+0x4d:
7705bef6 0fb74638        movzx   eax,word ptr [esi+38h]   ds:0023:00000037=????
Resetting default scope

FAULTING_IP: 
ntdll!LdrpUpdateLoadCount2+4d
7705bef6 0fb74638        movzx   eax,word ptr [esi+38h]

EXCEPTION_RECORD:  (.exr -1)
ExceptionAddress: 7705bef6 (ntdll!LdrpUpdateLoadCount2+0x0000004d)
   ExceptionCode: c0000005 (Access violation)
  ExceptionFlags: 00000000
NumberParameters: 2
   Parameter[0]: 00000000
   Parameter[1]: 00000037
Attempt to read from address 00000037

DEFAULT_BUCKET_ID:  NULL_CLASS_PTR_READ

PROCESS_NAME:  explorer.exe

ERROR_CODE: (NTSTATUS) 0xc0000005 - Die Anweisung in 0x%08lx verweist auf Speicher 0x%08lx. Der Vorgang %s konnte nicht im Speicher durchgef hrt werden.

FOLLOWUP_IP: 
TortoiseStub32!LoadRealLibrary+cd [d:\development\svn\releases\tortoisesvn-1.9.2\src\tortoiseshell\tortoisestub.cpp @ 191]
6ba2158d a3ac20a36b      mov     dword ptr [TortoiseStub32!hTortoiseSVN (6ba320ac)],eax

BUILD_VERSION_STRING:  6.1.7600.17206 (win7_gdr.130103-1435)

ANALYSIS_VERSION: 10.0.14321.1024 x86fre

THREAD_ATTRIBUTES: 
OS_LOCALE:  CHT

PROBLEM_CLASSES: 



NULL_CLASS_PTR_READ
    Tid    [0x96c]
    Frame  [0x00]: ntdll!LdrpUpdateLoadCount2


LAST_CONTROL_TRANSFER:  from 7705efa7 to 7705bef6

STACK_TEXT:  
0017e0d4 7705efa7 00000000 00000001 0017e2e8 ntdll!LdrpUpdateLoadCount2+0x4d
0017e0f0 77060022 00000000 00000001 771af35e ntdll!LdrpUpdateLoadCount2+0xff
0017e260 7705f4b9 0017e2c0 0017e28c 00000000 ntdll!LdrpLoadDll+0x358
0017e294 752cb96d 00365ea4 0017e2d8 0017e2c0 ntdll!LdrLoadDll+0x92
0017e2d0 6ba2158d 00000000 00000000 00365ea4 KERNELBASE!LoadLibraryExW+0x1d3
0017e4f4 6ba21648 0017e540 6ba41b82 0017e588 TortoiseStub32!LoadRealLibrary+0xcd
0017e4fc 6ba41b82 0017e588 6ba4e1b0 0017e53c TortoiseStub32!DllGetClassObject+0x8
WARNING: Stack unwind information not available. Following frames may be wrong.
0017e540 6ba41a9e 0017e9a8 0017f8ac 00000104 TortoiseOverlays+0x1b82
0017edc0 6ba4154d 0017f8ac 00000104 0017f670 TortoiseOverlays+0x1a9e
0017f634 76017702 003261b8 0017f8ac 00000104 TortoiseOverlays+0x154d
0017fba8 76017599 00000000 0031bda0 76017569 shell32!CFSIconOverlayManager::_s_LoadIconOverlayIdentifiers+0x17b
0017fbb4 76017569 0017fc44 80004005 00002000 shell32!CFSIconOverlayManager::_InitializeHdsaIconOverlays+0xb
0017fbc8 760174e0 00000000 76017508 0017fbdc shell32!CFSIconOverlayManager::CreateInstance+0x4e
0017fbe4 7602c203 00000000 00000001 0017fc4c shell32!IconOverlayManagerInit+0x2a
0017fbf4 7601710a 0017fc44 80000000 00000001 shell32!GetIconOverlayManager+0x17
0017fc4c 004e2dcf 00000001 00571fec 00000001 shell32!FileIconInit+0x218
0017fcf8 004ea800 004c0000 00000000 002f232a explorer!wWinMain+0x40f
0017fd8c 75821154 7ffff000 0017fdd8 7705b2b9 explorer!_initterm_e+0x1b1
0017fd98 7705b2b9 7ffff000 771aece6 00000000 kernel32!BaseThreadInitThunk+0xe
0017fdd8 7705b28c 004ea677 7ffff000 00000000 ntdll!__RtlUserThreadStart+0x70
0017fdf0 00000000 004ea677 7ffff000 00000000 ntdll!_RtlUserThreadStart+0x1b


FAULTING_SOURCE_LINE:  d:\development\svn\releases\tortoisesvn-1.9.2\src\tortoiseshell\tortoisestub.cpp

FAULTING_SOURCE_FILE:  d:\development\svn\releases\tortoisesvn-1.9.2\src\tortoiseshell\tortoisestub.cpp

FAULTING_SOURCE_LINE_NUMBER:  191

FAULTING_SOURCE_CODE:  
   187:     lstrcat(ModuleName, L"\\TortoiseSVN32.dll");
   188: #endif
   189:     TRACE(L"LoadRealLibrary() - Load %s\n", ModuleName);
   190: 
>  191:     hTortoiseSVN = LoadLibraryEx(ModuleName, NULL, LOAD_WITH_ALTERED_SEARCH_PATH);
   192:     if (!hTortoiseSVN)
   193:     {
   194:         TRACE(L"LoadRealLibrary() - Fail\n");
   195:         hTortoiseSVN = NIL;
   196:         return;


MODULE_NAME: TortoiseStub32

IMAGE_NAME:  TortoiseStub32.dll

BUCKET_ID:  NULL_CLASS_PTR_READ_tortoisestub32!LoadRealLibrary+cd

PRIMARY_PROBLEM_CLASS:  NULL_CLASS_PTR_READ_tortoisestub32!LoadRealLibrary+cd

FAILURE_EXCEPTION_CODE:  c0000005

FAILURE_IMAGE_NAME:  TortoiseStub32.dll

BUCKET_ID_IMAGE_STR:  TortoiseStub32.dll

FAILURE_MODULE_NAME:  TortoiseStub32

BUCKET_ID_MODULE_STR:  TortoiseStub32

FAILURE_FUNCTION_NAME:  LoadRealLibrary

BUCKET_ID_MODVER_STR:  1.9.2.26806

FAILURE_SYMBOL_NAME:  TortoiseStub32.dll!LoadRealLibrary

FAILURE_BUCKET_ID:  NULL_CLASS_PTR_READ_c0000005_TortoiseStub32.dll!LoadRealLibrary

BUILDOSVER_STR:  6.1.7600.17206

FAILURE_ID_HASH_STRING:  um:null_class_ptr_read_c0000005_tortoisestub32.dll!loadreallibrary
```

Remove TSVN (if this is not possible, rename the TortoiseSVN folder and look if Explorer runs again. if yes, install [TSVN 1.9.4](https://sourceforge.net/projects/tortoisesvn/files/1.9.4/Application/).

I see you also run the original Windows 7 Build 7600 which no longer gets updates. Install the [Windows 7 Sp1](https://www.microsoft.com/en-US/download/details.aspx?id=5842) + all missing updates. After updating to Sp1, [install the June 216 Update Rollup on your own via the MSU, so that Windows Update doesn't hang at checking for updates.](https://superuser.com/a/996072/174557)

Comment: Thx so much dude, I have tsvn's name added a space and everything went right again.

Comment: Can anyone tell me how to view that dump and debug myself?

Comment: What is the program required to do that?

Comment: the program is called Windbg.exe which is part of the Windows SDK.

Comment: do you still have a question? if not, click on the green checkmark to "close" the question.

Comment: Thx so much. No more question. Question closed.