# Windows Update Still Hangs at Checking For Updates in Win 7

Tags: windows-7, windows, freeze, updates

I have tried a number of these "solutions," yet I still have this issue. And I know this has been asked, but as I said, no suggested solution has worked. I have gone as far as running a Factory Restore on my system and STILL have issues.  The supposed work-arounds Microsoft has suggested don't even download.  Has MS actually ended Win7 support early? It's like getting a number nobody answers.  This is really frustrating.

(not that it matters, but SOMEONE will ask)
Factory Shipped w/ Win 7 Pro SP1
Lenovo Thinkpad X1 Carbon
Intel i7-3667U CPU @ 2GHz
8 G RAM
64-bit
SSD

Tried running over WiFi and Gigabit Ethernet with the same results.  I can download and surf everywhere else.
Ran Disk Cleanup from Safe Mode
Tried downloading direct from MS, but nothing is downloaded. (I also find it crass they actually tell you to "run Windows Update" when that's what the issue is!)
Even left my computer up with WU checking all night, nothing.
Yes, I have run virus and malware scans. This is happening on a fresh "refresh," too. So...

Is this just Microsoft's chinsy way of forcing people to upgrade to 10?  Because it sure seems like it.  I've been working with this issue for over a week now, so you can understand my frustration.

EDIT:  This is marked as a duplicate but it is not.  I indicated I have tried all downloads from MS, none of which have worked.  The solutions suggested here have been tried too, so, posting this was a last-ditch effort.

Comment: install the July 2016 update rollup from my answer in the dup link: http://superuser.com/a/996072/174557

Comment: That was one of the suggestions I've tried, Seems that any downloads from M$ don't function on my machine.  I can go anywhere else on the web and download, just not from M$.

Comment: what doesn't work? Stop the WU service, double click the MSU, reboot and now search for updates and they show up in a few minutes

Comment: The marked duplicate is a fairly recent question with 7 answers.  It had 1.5 million views and the question and answers have hundreds of upvotes.  That's the go-to question where any new answers are likely to be posted.  That represents the collective knowledge of the site's users.  Posting another question to ask the same thing won't bring you other answers.

Comment: @Qballrail - You can use, WSUSOffline, to generate a list of patches you need, then install them.  This avoids the abnormal long search times with Windows update, because its an expotenal growth, the patches listed for the cumalitve updates solve that problem though.

Comment: Look guys, this is a little different than the one already posted.  I would not have posted it otherwise.  I've TRIED those solutions as I said.  The difference is, as stated, is that for some reason, NOTHING downloads from M$ to my laptop. Telling me this is a duplicate question is not helping.

Comment: @Ramhound - I will try WSUSOffline.  That is one I have not seen yet. It is useful in that I will at least know what I have and do not have.  But it still does not address the fact that M$ does not respond to any download requests.

Comment: @Magicandre1981 - WU Service was stopped, but no DL frm M$. Actually did that the other day... but M$ still does not respond to DL req.

Comment: BTW, I do appreciate all the responses.  @ Mokubai -  I do think my question was hastily marked as an exact duplicate of one already asked, because of the differences stated, e.g., direct download request from MS result in no response. I have no problems anywhere else on the web.  And it is a legit copy of Windows, came from the mfr of my laptop.

Comment: @Qballrail - There are lots of a reasons Microsoft would not respond to download requests, some, could be entirely on your end.  Lets not use silly acronyms like M$ shall we?

Comment: what do you mean with DL respond? Get the MSU from here: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=53332 and double click on it after stopping WU service

Comment: @magicandre1981 - Ummm... like I said, I cannot download from M$. And I have done it after stopping WU service.  No, it is not on my end. I can download from any other site BUT M$. That's what I am trying to say.

Answer (score -1):

Install both of those updates manually:

```
kb/3020369
kb/3125574
```

Note:
I don't have 10 reputation, yet, so I can't post the links to those, if I want to keep the article-link in my answer .. but in the link below you can find the links to those udpates.

After a reboot the update-process should work more efficiently.
Also, when I had the same problem, I just kept the update running over night and at some time during the night, it actually started doing it's job. If that is an option, you could try that.

This article also might help (it includes the links from above and describes everything in more detail):
https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/windowsitpro/2016/05/17/simplifying-updates-for-windows-7-and-8-1/