# Windows 7 64 bit crash-tastic week

Tags: windows-7, 64-bit, bsod

I was directed here by a friend, and I'm hoping I'm not out of line by asking this seemingly small question. My Windows 7 64-bit PC started crashing recently, and this morning's BSOD flashed something about a "hardware malfunction" which I've never seen before. I have the .dmp file posted.

Specs: Q6600 2.4 GHZ 6 GB ram Nvidia 250 GTS (used to be a 660, but it was totally unstable)

I have used CCleaner, Argente utilities, Runscanner, and the Guru3d driver sweeper. Probably time for a rebuild anyway, but money...

[Crash dump file](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B0WrWMT7b8TdWWM0clpnRmFNMFk)

Comment: Run a memory diagnostic on it, see if there are any memory errors, it can be found in the all programs menu or open a run box (win key+R) and enter MdSched.exe>ok

Answer (score 0):

[Analyzing the dump with Windbg](http://channel9.msdn.com/Shows/Defrag-Tools/Defrag-Tools-15-WinDbg-Bugchecks) shows that you got the [KMODE_EXCEPTION_NOT_HANDLED (1e) bugcheck](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff557408(v=vs.85).aspx).

```
 # Call Site
00 nt!KeBugCheck
01 nt!KiKernelCalloutExceptionHandler
02 nt!RtlpExecuteHandlerForException
03 nt!RtlDispatchException
04 nt!KiDispatchException
05 nt!KiExceptionDispatch
06 nt!KiGeneralProtectionFault
07 nt!PoIdle
08 nt!KiIdleLoop

    Loaded symbol image file: ntkrnlmp.exe
    Mapped memory image file: d:\sym\dl\nt\ntoskrnl.exe\4E02AAA35e9000\ntoskrnl.exe
    Image path: ntkrnlmp.exe
    Image name: ntkrnlmp.exe
    Browse all global symbols  functions  data
    Timestamp:        Thu Jun 23 04:53:23 2011 (4E02AAA3)
    CheckSum:         0055C228
    ImageSize:        005E9000
    File version:     6.1.7601.17640
    Product version:  6.1.7601.17640
    File flags:       0 (Mask 3F)
    File OS:          40004 NT Win32
    File type:        1.0 App
    File date:        00000000.00000000
    Translations:     0409.04b0
    CompanyName:      Microsoft Corporation
    ProductName:      Microsoft® Windows® Operating System
    InternalName:     ntkrnlmp.exe
    OriginalFilename: ntkrnlmp.exe
    ProductVersion:   6.1.7601.17640
    FileVersion:      6.1.7601.17640 (win7sp1_gdr.110622-1506)
    FileDescription:  NT Kernel & System
    LegalCopyright:   © Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.
```

I see that your Patchlevel is from 2011. [Stop the WU service, install the July 2016 Update Rollup](https://superuser.com/a/996072/174557), reboot and let Windows install all missing updates. Now check if you still have issues.

Comment: Installer encountered error 0xc80003f3 while updating. Following that trail down the rabbit hole...

Comment: 0xc80003f3 = hrOutOfMemory . do a clean boot to eleminate all 3rd party tools that can consume RAM and now install the update.