# Blue screen Errors in Every Windows

Tags: windows-7, bsod

please can any one help me i am facing blue screen errors since 1 year. i tried to reinstall almost every windows and updated my drivers and updating my windows but nothing happens and i am facing different types of blue screen error. the most occurring Blue screen of death is resource_not_owned and i am fed up with this. any one can ask any information to me.
But I am not getting blue screen in safe mode. can anyone tell me what is causing blue screen?
My mini dump files are [Here](https://www.datafilehost.com/d/299c734f)

(edit):- Dropbox link is [Here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/a79vqsgdgds9auu/Minidump.rar?dl=0).

edit:- i was getting bluescreen in safemode before but now i am not getting it in safemode.

Edit:- i got a bluescreen with a driver name:-aswSP.sys . here is the link for [Screenshot](https://www.dropbox.com/s/weu13ki8hxhqa8c/IMG_20161114_131233.jpg?dl=0).

Edit:- here is the [Screenschot](https://www.dropbox.com/s/3kd731hm3fe2vbb/update.png?dl=0) while updating windows and i faced about 9-10 blue screen errors while updating windows.

EDIT:I checked my drivers using driver verifier i add all the drivers leaving microsoft corporation to verifier and i got some bluescreen errors during use of my Notebook. I found the drivers aswspsec.sys=avast and BCM42rly.sys=? errors and i uninstalled avast and my broadcom wireless driver and i am still facing bluescreen error with IRQL_NOT_LESS_OR_EQUAL and no DMP files are created during this error and i don't know what to do now and i tested my RAM upto 8 passes through memtest and there is no error in my RAM.

[DMP FILES](http://I%20checked%20my%20drivers%20using%20driver%20verifier%20i%20add%20all%20the%20drivers%20leaving%20microsoft%20corporation%20to%20verifier%20and%20i%20got%20some%20bluescreen%20errors%20during%20use%20of%20my%20Notebook.%20I%20found%20the%20drivers%20aswspsec.sys=avast%20and%20BCM42rly.sys=?%20errors%20and%20i%20uninstalled%20avast%20and%20my%20broadcom%20wireless%20driver%20and%20i%20am%20still%20facing%20bluescreen%20error%20with%20IRQL_NOT_LESS_OR_EQUAL%20and%20no%20DMP%20files%20are%20created%20during%20this%20error%20and%20i%20don't%20know%20what%20to%20do%20now%20and%20i%20tested%20my%20RAM%20upto%208%20passes%20through%20memtest%20and%20there%20is%20no%20error%20in%20my%20RAM.%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20DMP%20files.[link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/tftz4b2l7w7tlkf/New%20folder.rar?dl=0))

Comment: upload it somewhere else, the hoster is not working for me

Comment: The error is listed as `WIN7_DRIVER_FAULT` by several processes. I've looked through a few of your .dmp files and the processes I've seen so far are `explorer.exe`, `prezinext.wind`, `rzfpsapplet.ex`, `chrome.exe` and several other things. Due to the randomness of the applications that are causing the crash, I'd test your RAM to see if you have a bad stick. You can test your RAM by running [Memtest86](http://www.memtest86.com/)

Comment: i already tested my RAM and there is no fault in my RAM and i also changed my RAM but blue screen of death still occurs.

Comment: I check the last 2 dzmps and they show  INVALID_KERNEL_CONTEXT_0xE3 error. test your CPU with prime95 and look if it detcts errors. also update the BIOS from A10 to A11 and install all windows 7 updates, you use the clean Win7 Sp1 from 2011. To get Windows Update working, check this topic: http://superuser.com/a/996072/174557

Comment: have you run HW diag tools? Is the hardware fine?

Comment: as u told me to check my CPU using prime95 and i ran prime95 for 3hrs and i didn't got any error. and i had already ran diagnostic test and my hardware is fine.

Comment: aswSP.sys = Avast AV suite. Remove it Have you done a memtest?

Comment: i cannot remove avast i want one antivirus in my computer and i had done memtest there are no problems in RAM. i was updating my windows and i am facing too many bluescreen errors during updating. what should i do?

Comment: will bluescreen stop after updating windows???

Comment: for testing purpose remove Avast and use Microsoft Security Essentials

Comment: I checked my drivers using driver verifier i add all the drivers leaving microsoft corporation to verifier and i got some bluescreen errors during use of my Notebook. I found the drivers aswspsec.sys=avast and BCM42rly.sys=? errors and i uninstalled avast and my broadcom wireless driver and i am still facing bluescreen error with IRQL_NOT_LESS_OR_EQUAL and no DMP files are created during this error and i don't know what to do now and i tested my RAM upto 8 passes through memtest and there is no error in my RAM.

Comment: BCM42rly.sys looks like Broadcom (WiFI) driver. so update this driver

Comment: it is upto date.

Comment: i think that my problem gets solved. if BSOD again occurs i will tell.

Comment: and how have you solved it? updating broadcom driver and removing avast?