# Windows update failed with 0x80070003

Tags: windows-10, windows-update, updates

I can't update my windows 10 with the KB4549951 update. Windows keeps rolling back my update during the restart. The error message said "Failed to install" with error code 0x80070003.

What I have tried:

- Everything suggested by this [similar question](https://superuser.com/questions/1147789/windows-updates-stopped-working-with-error-0x80244010-and-0x80070003)

  - Stopping/restarting windows update service
  - Delete C:\Windows\SoftwareDistribution
- Windows update troubleshooter shows no error.
- Delete DataStore folder
- Run `DISM /Online /Cleanup-Image /ScanHealth` and `Dism /Online /Cleanup-Image /RestoreHealth`. Both show no error.
- `sfc /scannow` shows no error.

However, the CBS log in C:\Windows\Logs\CBS shows `ERROR_PATH_NOT_FOUND` errors, which might have something to do with the update.

```
2020-04-23 22:27:49, Info                  CBS    DriverUpdateInstallUpdates failed [HRESULT = 0x80070003 - ERROR_PATH_NOT_FOUND]
2020-04-23 22:27:49, Info                  CBS    Doqe: Failed installing driver updates [HRESULT = 0x80070003 - ERROR_PATH_NOT_FOUND]
2020-04-23 22:27:49, Info                  CBS    Perf: Doqe: Install ended.
2020-04-23 22:27:49, Info                  CBS    Failed installing driver updates [HRESULT = 0x80070003 - ERROR_PATH_NOT_FOUND]
2020-04-23 22:27:49, Error                 CBS    Shtd: Failed while processing non-critical driver operations queue. [HRESULT = 0x80070003 - ERROR_PATH_NOT_FOUND]
2020-04-23 22:27:49, Info                  CBS    Shtd: Rolling back KTM, because drivers failed.
2020-04-23 22:27:49, Info                  CBS    SetProgressMessage: progressMessageStage: 4, ExecuteState: CbsExecuteStatePrimitives, SubStage: 0
2020-04-23 22:27:49, Info                  CBS    Progress: UI message updated. Operation type: Update. Stage: 0 out of 0. Temporary Rollback.
2020-04-23 22:27:49, Info                  CBS    Shtd: progress thread terminating. [HRESULT = 0x00000000 - S_OK]
2020-04-23 22:27:49, Info                  CBS    Shtd: progress thread terminated normally
2020-04-23 22:27:49, Info                  CBS    Doqe: Unlocking driver updates, Count 266
2020-04-23 22:27:49, Info                  CBS    Winlogon: Simplifying Winlogon CreateSession notifications
2020-04-23 22:27:49, Info                  CBS    Shtd: Shutdown processing complete.
```

Windows specifications:

- Edition: Windows 10 Pro
- Version: 1909
- OS build: 18363.752

I have been going at this for a few days now. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: 0x80070003 = WinError 3 so the command _net helpmsg 3 The system cannot find the path specified._ https://winsourcecode.blogspot.com/2019/12/decoding-errors.html

Comment: That makes sense. But what path though? Shouldn't the windows update client handle path finding? Or is there some setting I'm missing?

Comment: Have a look at this>>>>>>>https://www.bleepingcomputer.com/news/microsoft/windows-10-kb4549951-update-fails-to-install-causes-bsods/

Comment: @Moab Thanks for the link. It seems that a lot of people are having the same problem as me. The article didn't provide any solutions though. I have tried to use windows update catalog before. The download got stuck at 0%.

Comment: Hopefully windows telemetry will report the issues with that patch to Microsoft and will get fixed for next patch Tuesday.