# Recent batch of updates has caused Windows Update to stop working

Tags: windows-7, windows-update

After 3 years of not updating, new software required me to update so I have been updating all available important updates. Started at 130h and then I got to the final 5.

They all appeared to install ok, computer restarted after the updates but now when I click Windows Update it doesn't go to the next screen - just hangs with the loading graphic.

I tried slimming down my startup services but the Troubleshoot just reported "Windows could not automatically detect this network's proxy settings". I've re-added services but now Troubleshoot is just hanging (currently waited 30 mins) on Detecting Problems - Checking for updates online.

I've also noticed that Windows Explorer has started acting funny - sometimes not starting and sometimes not loading the Aero graphics.

What steps should I take to try and fix my problem? Is there a way to uninstall the last batch - and is that a good/bad idea?

**Edit:**

I renamed the Windows/SoftwareDistribution which has given me access back to Windows Update. I'm now running it again.

Comment: It is very difficult to imagine avoiding updating your operating system for three years, and then trying to integrate everything you have missed all at once without encountering any problems.  That being said, there is a previous question with [some excellent advice regarding how to install a large number Windows 7 updates](https://superuser.com/questions/951960/windows-7-sp1-windows-update-stuck-checking-for-updates) relatively smoothly.  It would probably be beneficial to give it a thorough reading.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Renaming/moving the `C:/Windows/SoftwareDistribution` folder fixed the issue. After a couple of restarts/shutdowns the Windows Update is also showing progress whereas previously it never updated.