# Windows 7 Excessive Memory Usage & Paging

Tags: windows-7, memory, paging

New user here, signed up because I saw similar posts through a Google search.

I have Windows 7 x64 w/8 Gigs of memory installed. The typical memory usage that I see is 2 gigs. That's what I would consider normal.

The problem is that it's now spiking, several times a day, to 7 gigs of usage and it's paging to disk to the point that the computer is not enjoyable.

I believe it may be related to Windows Media Center but am not certain. I cannot see anything that stands out in task manager. It does not appear to show there. I did install Windows Performance Recorder but am not certain how to use it.

I'm pretty much at the end of my rope. With nothing running on the machine it will still spike to 7 Gigs for a period, and then drop back to 2.

If there's anyone out there that is able to troubleshoot this with me, I'd appreciate it. I have no issue with posting pics or following steps.

It seems to do this with a clean install. It's not a virus or anything simple. It's pretty clear that this is some form of memory leak. Either that or, let's say, twice a day it's doing something that's using up a huge amount of memory. If I leave it, it will eventually finish (?) and go back to 2 GB or thereabouts.

Comment: Do you have all current windows updates installed? Why not link the other posts? Did you try the solutions from those? How did you find/come up with the idea of installing Windows Performance Recorder?  Did that source have a manual on how to use it? Usually you'd record a time-frame and analyze it afterwards for what you're looking for. In your case probably RAM usage.

Comment: In addition to @Seth 's comment: 2GB for Windows 7 x64 is not normal - its normal for system in idle straight after booting (well, ~1.8 GB). Run anything and RAM usage should spike. If it's fresh installation, then what you see is updates being installed.. It will subside after a while. And memory leak is usually uncontrolled - if it's returning to normal after some time, it's definitely by design. Again: most probably updates.

Comment: Wu scan can also cause such high mem usage. MS fixed it with July 2016 rollup: http://superuser.com/a/996072/174557