# How to slipstream updates into a Windows 7 disk or ISO?

Tags: windows-7, installation, windows-update

Windows 7 SP1 64 bit ISO or fresh install can't talk to Microaoft because of the new update mechanism. I would like to slipstream the requisite updates into a USB stick installer.  I have the requisite update(s), but all guides point to software no longer posted to do the slipstreaming.

NTLite looks like it can do slipstreaming, but it's only patching the host OS, therefore, I'm not aure what its purpose actually is.

Guides only mention RT se7en, and the 64 bit version is MIA. I found the x86 version though.

If I want to slipstream updates into a Windows 7, how do I do that?

Comment: You can use the DISM tool to create a new install.wim based on an existing installation or use the tools you mention to add the update to the wim file

Comment: I install updates via setupcomplete.cmd after install. http://windows-unattended.org/viewtopic.php?f=15&t=249&start=10. Here the install.wim is not modified and new update can be replaced much easier. To have a fast WU, include the april 2015 servicing staCK Update and the july 2016 rollup: http://superuser.com/a/996072/174557

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The post [here](https://superuser.com/questions/951960/windows-7-sp1-windows-update-stuck-checking-for-updates/996072#996072) should do the trick.  Not sure why I couldn't find it before.

I was also able to find the 64 bit version of RT se7en on [Softpedia](http://www.softpedia.com/get/System/Boot-Manager-Disk/RT-Seven-Lite.shtml#download).  That worked to a certain extent, but I didn't get it 100% right the first time and may try again.