# Windows 7 Windows Update stuck on 0%, deleted DataStore file now stuck on checking for update

Tags: windows-7, windows-update, patch

I realize there are already some question feeds related to my current question (see [Windows 7 SP1 Windows Update stuck checking for updates](https://superuser.com/questions/951960/windows-7-sp1-windows-update-stuck-checking-for-updates)). I am still confused as to why there is this disconnect between Windows 7 and the new windows update servers.

I suspect there is a server connection problem because when I try and monitor   C:->Windows-> SoftwareDistribution folder the size remains unchanged even while the WindowsUpdate program claims to be working.

Comment: [su] is a question and answer site and answers should be separate from questions. You can [answer your own question](http://superuser.com/help/self-answer) instead.

Answer (score 1):

After I tried several different techniques found in the SuperUser community I still was unable to update my Windows 7 Dell Latitude, so I looked to the Microsoft Community for some help.

According to a Microsoft Community post (https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wiki/windows_7-update/fix-windows-7-update-stuck-on-checking-for-updates/ad6cfeef-232a-49b4-a57b-39978eea6630) there seems to be an 'incompatibility between Windows 7 and Microsoft Update Servers' after the latest release of Microsoft Windows 10. It appears you need to update your computer with 5 patches to bring your computer online with the new servers.

I went through the patch wizard found in the above link, which required around 15 minutes with occasional bash input. My computer is now updating properly.

Comment: [Windows 7 SP1 Windows Update stuck checking for updates](http://superuser.com/questions/951960/windows-7-sp1-windows-update-stuck-checking-for-updates?noredirect=1&lq=1) implicently indicates you needed those updates.  The accepted answer and your link both indicate you need the convenience roll-up to install Windows 7 patches released after April 2015.  This requirement existed long before any update to Windows 10, and infact, Windows 10 has nothing to do with this required patch.  Only KB3020369 and KB3172605 are required to fix this issue.