# after running all day, stopped update download on W7 and it cancels the entire download

Tags: windows-7

as will become obvious right away i am no techie. i used to be ok at it, but after brain surgeries i get screwed up easily. in the past when i get an auto update on windows 7, it downloaded what it could during on time and installed whatever updates it completed either as i powered down, or powered up the next day. but all the sudden, during the entire update is continually says 'downloading 33 updates (0 KB total, 0% complete) it NEVER CHANGES!! but still at least ACTS like it is downloading. this time i left it on for TWO DAYS, and it still says not complete - and i just know when i power it off in a few minutes, it's gonna say 'cancelled 33 updates'

can ANYONE tell me what might be going on - i'm on comcast wifi, have noticed no real change in the speed of things as i work, but am getting WAY aggravated, confused and ready to toss the thing out the window! hope you can help a far-from-super-user. =^,,^=

Comment: make sure you use latest Windows update client: http://superuser.com/a/996072/174557 this fixes perf issues with Windows update

Answer (score 2):

Try opening up Windows Update, and seeing the list of the updates it wants to install. You can untick each one to say not to install it right now, and just leave one update ticked. Try installing that update by pressing the install updates button. Then tick one more update and install that, and so on.

It may be the case that there is one update that won't download for some reason, and is freezing the process. If you can install the other updates and narrow down which one is an issue, then you can either:

1. try to download that update's installer manually from Microsoft by searching for the relevant kbxxxxxx listed in the description
2. right click and hide the problem update in Windows Update so that it stops bothering you

(Also, I'm assuming your internet connection works...)