# How to diagnose abnormal CPU usage by svchost.exe?

Tags: windows-7, windows, services, cpu-usage

I've got a laptop with a Win 7 32-bit system powered by a dual-core Pentium (it's a 2010 laptop). Sometimes it works fine, but usually it idles at 100% CPU load. The CPU is consumed by two svchost.exe processes (50% each). As far as I understand, this is a service host. Is there any way to find out which service is the culprit?

Of note: this happens even in safe mode.

Comment: You can use process explorer to look at the services that are running under the two instances of svchost  ( https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/processexplorer.aspx )

Comment: @Yorik: I thought of that, but ProcessExplorer showed nothing of use.

Comment: In Windows 7, I would say that currently >90% of svchost CPU issues are related to the Windows Update service. If you have real trouble getting a system up-to-date (which may be difficult on a fresh install with an old processor), try to install KB3050265, KB3138612 and KB3145739 without a network connection. Then reboot and search for updates.

Comment: @ontrack: Interesting. Actually, I think checking for updates is disabled on this machine, it probably wasn't ever updated since 2010 or 2012. And I have no desire to install updates, I just need to fix the CPU issue. If you're right, will simply disabling the Windows Update service help?

Comment: this was asked so many times. see dup. You likely see the WU scnaning issue. Solve it from steps in my answer: https://superuser.com/a/996072/174557

Comment: To the person nominating for reopening: Can you please detail how the linked duplicates do not answer your specific question?

Comment: @music2myear: I'm not that person, but IMO the accepted answer here beats the answers there.

Answer (score 27):

As an instance of svchost.exe hosts multiple system services, here is how
to separate the services, each to his own instance of svchost.exe,
so as to find out which service consumes the CPU.

The procedure is as follows :

1. Use Task Manager to show all processes sorted by CPU descending
   and mark the PID of the processes that consume the CPU
2. In a Command Prompt (cmd) enter the command
   `Tasklist /svc /fi "IMAGENAME eq svchost.exe"`
   [image]
3. The problematic instances of svchost.exe can now be located by their PID
   and on the right you will find a list of the system services that they host
4. For each of the names in the list enter the following command in a
   Command Prompt (cmd) that is Run as administrator:
   `sc config <name> type= own`
   (Note the space between the ‘=’ and ‘own’)
5. Reboot

The system services that you separated will now each run in its own instance
of svchost.exe and can be seen in Task Manager in the Processes tab.
You may right-click on an instance and select "Go to Service(s)"
to go directly to the service, or use again the tasklist command.

For more information see the Microsoft article
[Getting Started with SVCHOST.EXE Troubleshooting](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/askperf/2008/01/11/getting-started-with-svchost-exe-troubleshooting/).

Answer (score 8):

[Process Explorer](https://technet.microsoft.com/sysinternals/processexplorer.aspx) makes this easy.  I have confirmed this works with Process Explorer v16.20 on 64-bit Windows 7 Professional and 64-bit Windows 10 Pro.

1. Run Process Explorer elevated.
2. Locate an `svchost.exe` process with a high (or even just measureable/non-blank) value in the `CPU` column.  Sorting by the `Process` or `CPU` column may assist with this.
3. Right-click the `svchost.exe` process and select `Properties...`.
4. In the process properties window, select the `Threads` tab.  All of the threads in this process will be displayed.
5. Locate a thread with a high (or, again, just measurable/non-blank) value in the `CPU` column.  Sorting by the `CPU` column may assist with this.[image: Process Explorer process Threads tab]
6. The `Service` column will show the name of the service in which that thread is running.

If the service name is not familiar to you...

7. In the process properties window, select the `Services` tab.  All of the services that run in this process will be displayed.
8. Match the `Service` column on the `Services` tab to the value of the `Service` column on the `Threads` tab you located in step 6.[image: Process Explorer process Services tab]
9. The `Display Name` column will display the friendly name of the service.  The description of the selected service will appear below the list of services.

Comment: Ah, I didn't know about those advanced functions of Process Explorer. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

You can use *Task Manager*. There are other ways (command line, or even write some program using *WinAPI*), but I won't discuss them here. Before going any further, your user should have administrative privileges.

On the *Processes* tab:

- Check *Show processes from all users*.
- Right click on the processes "table header" (that contains column names like *Image name*, *PID*, *User Name*, *CPU*, ...), and select *Select Columns...*.

  - On the dialog that pops-up, scroll down and make sure you check *Command line*, and *PID (Process Identifier)* then press *OK*.
- Back to the *Processes* tab, click on *CPU* column header so that the processes will be ordered by their CPU consumption (note that the processes might be displayed in ascending/descending order - each click on *CPU* switches the orders), click until the 2 processes appear at the top of the table. Now you''re able to see their command line (I don't know but I have a feeling that one of them is `netsvcs` (Network Services)) and also their PIDs.
- Next, you need to match the 2 processes to the services. For that you can either:

  - Right click on them and then *Go to service(s)...*. This will move to the *Services* tab, having all the service running in that process selected (for this option you don't need any of the previous steps :) ).
  - Open the *Services* snapin in *mmc*. When double clikc-ing on a service (only makes sense to check the ones that are running), Under *Path to executable* you can see their command line that you should do the match on.
- On *W10* you can view the exact info you need from *Resource Monitor* (you can start it from *Task Manager*, *Performance* tab). There you go to *CPU* tab and the services and their CPU consumption are listed.

*EDIT0*: Updated answer to provide a simpler (and making way more sense) approach, instead of *scratching my right head side using my left hand* style one, that I initially posted.

Comment: I never noticed you can see the command line, neat! Not as straightforward as harrymc's answer, but good to know.

Comment: Task Manager can do that on its own. If a svchost process is selected when switching to the Services tab, the services running in that process will be selected there.

Comment: Really? On _W10_ this doesn't happen (at least when there's some service already selected). The only way is by _rclick_'ing on the process, and then choose _Go to service(s)_ (option that I missed - most likely it exists in _W7_ as well). Unfortunately I'm not able to check.

Comment: @CristiFati this option has existed since Windows Vista (source: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff642468.aspx ), you should probably add it to your answer instead of the PID matching by hand