# One executable backgroundTaskHost.exe with many different Process Name

Tags: windows, command-line, process, windows-10-v1703

OS Windows 10 Pro 64bit version 1703 build 15063.

- When I start up the machine it shows two processes in Task Manager (disappear after 2 minutes). Two process have the same executable file (.exe) which is **backgroundTaskHost.exe**. But with two different process name.
- First one is with process name "Cortana Background Task Host" and with command line `"C:\Windows\system32\backtgroundTaskHost.exe" -ServerName:CortanaUI.AppXy7vb4pc2dr3kc93kfc509b1d0arkfb2x.mca`.

[image: Image:Cortana Background Task Host]

- Second one is with process name "Microsoft Account Background Task Host" and with command line `"C:\Windows\system32\backgroundTaskHost.exe" -ServerName:App.AppXmtcan0h2tfbfy7k9kn8hbxb6dmzz1zh0.mca`.

[image: Image:Microsoft Account Background Task Host]

- My questions are::
- How is this possible to use one executable in two process name?
- And what are the *-ServerName* options in command line?
- Is the .mca a file extension? Where is it stored?
- Where the full .mca file name saved?

---

Update:: There are **fourteen different command line** associated with that background task and all are **metro apps** linked with it. Here all the images given::

## [Photos::Windows Metro Apps](https://photos.google.com/share/AF1QipOVVLR_uyEzDQhkooaHdNeq78O1e5KEN2mQGMryhssdABj8RwrlI5SRfix8UT2SFA?key=ckR6NWRERWFITEhZUnhZN09IQi1WcTkxTThZRy13)

Comment: A name is just a name, the application sets it when it runs. In this case, the exe is a wrapper for running applications in the background. Server is a phrase used to indicate a background task, a daemon in UNIX terms.

Comment: It isn't really an answer so probably not. Not sure what more you want. The exe runs other code, in this case wrapped up in a file with a .mca extension. The name will be set from the code in the mca file. I don't know whether .mca files contain code or are configuration files pointing to code.

Comment: as I already said, those a re all background tasks. so you have 14 apps that use background tasks to do work when they don't run in foreground /getting current weather data, photo app my upload the taken photos to onedrive and so one). We can't add more details, we don't code them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Windows 10 the Task Manager has become much more beautiful, but it has also
lost some information.

The Task Manager of Windows 7 has distinguished between Application Name
and Process Name. While the later is derived from the executable file-name,
the Application Name is either derived from the title of the main top-level
window of the application, or is specified when the process was launched
(see in the
[CreateProcess API](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682425(v=vs.85).aspx) the parameter `lpApplicationName`).

In your case, the parent of all the processes you cite is `svchost.exe`,
which is the process charged with the launching of system services.
Apparently, in Windows 10 it makes an effort to give the started service
a better application-name.
This is an improvement over Windows 7, where svchost was a black box
requiring [manipulations](https://superuser.com/a/1192108/8672)
to identify a wasteful service.

To summarize, **two processes with the same executable can have different application-names specified by invocation or by execution.**

Comment: Thanks! But from where did the .mca file name come?

Comment: @Biswa it's not necessarily a file - what you see is the process' command line. The name is clearly autogenerated. This looks like some unique temporary name (whether it's of a file, [Object Manager](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_Manager_(Windows)) object, named pipe or something else) that Task Scheduler service and `backgroundTaskHost.exe` use to communicate with each other.

Answer (score 2):

backgroundTaskHost.exe is the process that starts [background tasks](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/launch-resume/support-your-app-with-background-tasks). So Cortana and the other Microsoft app registered a background task which is now started by Windows.

Comment: this includes the name of the task that needs to run

Comment: [appx is the installer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_Windows_Platform_apps#APPX) format of the new store apps since Windows 8.1. please do some research on your own and use google.

Comment: I have no idea, this is not documented by Microsoft.

Comment: maybe it is a kind of hash to identify the task, but I don't know if this is correct.