# Computer restarts suddenly

Tags: bsod

So for a few weeks now my computer restarts randomly (never happened in front of me. Always happens when I turn on the pc and go away for a while).

So this the error Windows shows me

```
Problem signature:
  Problem Event Name:   BlueScreen
  OS Version:   6.1.7601.2.1.0.256.1
  Locale ID:    1033

Additional information about the problem:
  BCCode:   d1
  BCP1: 0000000000000028
  BCP2: 0000000000000002
  BCP3: 0000000000000000
  BCP4: FFFFF880015466FD
  OS Version:   6_1_7601
  Service Pack: 1_0
  Product:  256_1

Files that help describe the problem:
  C:\Windows\Minidump\061117-31683-01.dmp
  C:\Users\Deba-kun\AppData\Local\Temp\WER-132320-0.sysdata.xml
```

Comment: copy the file C:\Windows\Minidump\061117-31683-01.dmp to desktop, upload the file to OneDrive and post a share link here so that we can debug it

Comment: Ah sure.Here it is.

Comment: https://ufile.io/hzomr

Comment: ok, I posted what I saw from the dump

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Looking at the dump file with Windbg](https://channel9.msdn.com/Shows/Defrag-Tools/Defrag-Tools-15-WinDbg-Bugchecks) indicates and issue related to Network:

```
*******************************************************************************
*                                                                             *
*                        Bugcheck Analysis                                    *
*                                                                             *
*******************************************************************************

DRIVER_IRQL_NOT_LESS_OR_EQUAL (d1)
An attempt was made to access a pageable (or completely invalid) address at an
interrupt request level (IRQL) that is too high.  This is usually
caused by drivers using improper addresses.
If kernel debugger is available get stack backtrace.
Arguments:
Arg1: 0000000000000028, memory referenced
Arg2: 0000000000000002, IRQL
Arg3: 0000000000000000, value 0 = read operation, 1 = write operation
Arg4: fffff880015466fd, address which referenced memory

Debugging Details:
------------------


DUMP_CLASS: 1

DUMP_QUALIFIER: 400

BUILD_VERSION_STRING:  7601.18409.amd64fre.win7sp1_gdr.140303-2144

SYSTEM_MANUFACTURER:  Gigabyte Technology Co., Ltd.

SYSTEM_PRODUCT_NAME:  G41M-Combo

BIOS_VENDOR:  Award Software International, Inc.

BIOS_VERSION:  FA

BIOS_DATE:  02/29/2012

BASEBOARD_MANUFACTURER:  Gigabyte Technology Co., Ltd.

BASEBOARD_PRODUCT:  G41M-Combo

BASEBOARD_VERSION:  x.x

DUMP_TYPE:  2

STACK_TEXT:
00 nt!KeBugCheckEx
01 nt!KiBugCheckDispatch
02 nt!KiPageFault
03 NETIO!RtlCopyBufferToMdl
04 tcpip! ?? ::FNODOBFM::`string'
05 tcpip!TcpTcbCarefulDatagram
06 tcpip!TcpTcbReceive
07 tcpip!TcpMatchReceive
08 tcpip!TcpPreValidatedReceive
09 tcpip!IppDeliverListToProtocol
0a tcpip!IppProcessDeliverList
0b tcpip!IppReceiveHeaderBatch
0c tcpip!IpFlcReceivePackets
0d tcpip!FlpReceiveNonPreValidatedNetBufferListChain
0e tcpip! ?? ::FNODOBFM::`string'
0f nt!KeExpandKernelStackAndCalloutEx
10 tcpip!FlReceiveNetBufferListChain
11 ndis!ndisMIndicateNetBufferListsToOpen
12 ndis!ndisMDispatchReceiveNetBufferLists
```

Using [PDE.dll](https://onedrive.live.com/?cid=dae128bd454cf957&id=DAE128BD454CF957%217152&ithint=folder,zip&authkey=!AJeSzeiu8SQ7T4w) to dump strings, shows 2 network related drivers that may cause it:

```
=========================================================================================
 PDE v10.0 - Copyright 2015 Andrew Richards
=========================================================================================
Start memory scan  : 0xfffff88002fd1748 ($csp)
End memory scan    : 0xfffff88002fd3000 (Kernel Stack Base)

               rsp : 0xfffff88002fd1748 : 0xfffff800036c1169 : nt!KiBugCheckDispatch+0x69
0xfffff88002fd1748 : 0xfffff800036c1169 : nt!KiBugCheckDispatch+0x69
0xfffff88002fd1770 : 0xfffff880015466fd : NETIO!RtlCopyBufferToMdl+0x1d
0xfffff88002fd1838 : 0xfffff88002d9783d : afd!AfdRestartDisconnect+0x1d
0xfffff88002fd1888 : 0xfffff800036bfde0 : nt!KiPageFault+0x260
0xfffff88002fd1890 : 0x0000000000000001 :  Trap @ fffff88002fd1890
0xfffff88002fd1898 : 0xfffff88001665882 : tcpip!TcpDequeueTcbSend+0x3c2
0xfffff88002fd18f8 : 0xfffff880015448be : NETIO!KfdAleFindFlowContextTable+0xe
0xfffff88002fd1988 : 0xfffff88001537d4b : NETIO!FsbFree+0x6b
0xfffff88002fd19a8 : 0xfffff88001660e5a : tcpip!IPSecTLPacketsInProcessing+0x3a
0xfffff88002fd19c8 : 0xfffff8800167ee0d : tcpip!TcpDisconnectTcbComplete+0x8d
0xfffff88002fd19f8 : 0xfffff880015466fd : NETIO!RtlCopyBufferToMdl+0x1d
0xfffff88002fd1a28 : 0xfffff8800164a845 : tcpip!TcpStartTimerTcb+0x45
0xfffff88002fd1a38 : 0xfffff880014461a7 : ndis!NdisFreeNetBufferList+0x87
0xfffff88002fd1a88 : 0xfffff88001676822 : tcpip!TcpTcbAcceptDatagram+0x162
0xfffff88002fd1a98 : 0xfffff8800164a845 : tcpip!TcpStartTimerTcb+0x45
0xfffff88002fd1b38 : 0xfffff88002fd1db8 : 0xfffff8800165b800 : tcpip!IppReceiveHeadersHelper+0x3b0
0xfffff88002fd1b68 : 0xfffff88001539316 : NETIO!NetioDereferenceNetBufferList+0x86
0xfffff88002fd1bf8 : 0xfffff88001660bc3 : tcpip!InetInspectReceiveDatagram+0x103
0xfffff88002fd1c08 : 0xfffff88001663345 : tcpip!TcpTcbFastDatagram+0x4d5
0xfffff88002fd1c98 : 0xfffff88001664f38 : tcpip!TcpTcbReceive+0x37c
0xfffff88002fd1cb8 : 0xfffff8800150217b : ndis!NdisReturnNetBufferLists+0x3b
0xfffff88002fd1cf8 : 0xfffff88001657f26 : tcpip!FlpReturnNetBufferListChain+0x96
0xfffff88002fd1da8 : 0xfffff8800166299a : tcpip!TcpMatchReceive+0x1fa
0xfffff88002fd1db8 : 0xfffff8800165b800 : tcpip!IppReceiveHeadersHelper+0x3b0
0xfffff88002fd1dc8 : 0xfffff88001671692 : tcpip!IpNlpConfirmForwardReachability+0xc2
0xfffff88002fd1e30 : 0xfffff88001769800 : tcpip!Ipv6Global
Unable to load image \SystemRoot\system32\DRIVERS\L1C62x64.sys, Win32 error 0n2
*** WARNING: Unable to verify timestamp for L1C62x64.sys
*** ERROR: Module load completed but symbols could not be loaded for L1C62x64.sys
0xfffff88002fd1ef8 : 0xfffff880016636cb : tcpip!TcpPreValidatedReceive+0x36b
0xfffff88002fd1f38 : 0xfffff88001667f2a : tcpip!TcpValidateReceive+0x1ba
0xfffff88002fd1f88 : 0xfffff88001769800 : tcpip!Ipv6Global
0xfffff88002fd1fc8 : 0xfffff8800165bf37 : tcpip!IppDeliverListToProtocol+0x97
0xfffff88002fd1ff8 : 0xfffff8800150221d : ndis!NdisMSendNetBufferListsComplete+0x6d
0xfffff88002fd2018 : 0xfffff88001668f9f : tcpip!TcpTcbSendDatagramsComplete+0x12f
0xfffff88002fd2038 : 0xfffff880041a0c8d : tunnel!TeredoWfpInjectComplete+0x71
0xfffff88002fd2088 : 0xfffff8800165baaa : tcpip!IppProcessDeliverList+0x5a
0xfffff88002fd2098 : 0xfffff88001769800 : tcpip!Ipv6Global
0xfffff88002fd20a8 : 0xfffff88001538a72 : NETIO!NetioDereferenceNetBufferListChain+0x332
0xfffff88002fd2128 : 0xfffff8800165b0a9 : tcpip!IppReceiveHeaderBatch+0x23a
0xfffff88002fd2200 : 0xfffff88001769800 : tcpip!Ipv6Global
0xfffff88002fd2208 : 0xfffff88001658d4f : tcpip!IpFlcReceivePackets+0x64f
0xfffff88002fd2220 : 0xfffff88001769800 : tcpip!Ipv6Global
0xfffff88002fd2228 : 0xfffff88001769800 : tcpip!Ipv6Global
Unable to load image \SystemRoot\system32\DRIVERS\wsnf.sys, Win32 error 0n2
*** WARNING: Unable to verify timestamp for wsnf.sys
*** ERROR: Module load completed but symbols could not be loaded for wsnf.sys
0xfffff88002fd22d8 : 0xfffff88001769800 : tcpip!Ipv6Global
0xfffff88002fd23b8 : 0xfffff88001446419 : ndis!ndisSendNBLToFilter+0x69
0xfffff88002fd2408 : 0xfffff88001658322 : tcpip!FlpReceiveNonPreValidatedNetBufferListChain+0x2b2
0xfffff88002fd2538 : 0xfffff800036cd878 : nt!KeExpandKernelStackAndCalloutEx+0xd8
0xfffff88002fd2598 : 0xfffff8800165d1c7 : tcpip!IppDispatchSendPacketHelper+0x87
0xfffff88002fd25a0 : 0xfffff8800176e9a0 : tcpip!Ipv4Global
0xfffff88002fd25d8 : 0xfffff8800153e0f1 : NETIO!NetioAllocateMdl+0xc1
0xfffff88002fd2618 : 0xfffff88001657e42 : tcpip!FlReceiveNetBufferListChain+0xb2
0xfffff88002fd2620 : 0xfffff88001657670 : tcpip!FlReceiveNetBufferListChainCalloutRoutine
0xfffff88002fd2688 : 0xfffff880015020eb : ndis!ndisMIndicateNetBufferListsToOpen+0xdb
0xfffff88002fd26f8 : 0xfffff880014cbad6 : ndis!ndisMDispatchReceiveNetBufferLists+0x1d6
0xfffff88002fd2728 : 0xfffff8800176e9a0 : tcpip!Ipv4Global
```

`L1C62x64.sys` is the qualcomm atheros gigabit Ethernet driver, yours is from 2012:

```
Image path: \SystemRoot\system32\DRIVERS\L1C62x64.sys
Image name: L1C62x64.sys
Browse all global symbols  functions  data
Timestamp:        Wed Apr 25 07:07:17 2012
```

The `wsnf.sys` seams to belong to `Quick Heal AntiVirus`:

```
Image path: \SystemRoot\system32\DRIVERS\wsnf.sys
Image name: wsnf.sys
Browse all global symbols  functions  data
Timestamp:        Fri Nov 28 16:14:12 2014
```

Also look if there is a newer product version of `Quick Heal AntiVirus` and update it. The driver is also 3 years old and maybe has issues.

The 2nd dump shows AMD driver issues:

```
*******************************************************************************
*                                                                             *
*                        Bugcheck Analysis                                    *
*                                                                             *
*******************************************************************************

VIDEO_SCHEDULER_INTERNAL_ERROR (119)
The video scheduler has detected that fatal violation has occurred. This resulted
in a condition that video scheduler can no longer progress. Any other values after
parameter 1 must be individually examined according to the subtype.
Arguments:
Arg1: 0000000000000001, The driver has reported an invalid fence ID.
Arg2: 0000000000001717
Arg3: 0000000000001910
Arg4: 000000000000190f

Debugging Details:
------------------

STACK_TEXT:
00 nt!KeBugCheckEx
01 watchdog!WdLogEvent5
02 dxgmms1!VidSchiVerifyDriverReportedFenceId
03 dxgmms1!VidSchDdiNotifyInterruptWorker
04 dxgmms1!VidSchDdiNotifyInterrupt
05 dxgkrnl!DxgNotifyInterruptCB
06 atikmpag
07 0x0
08 0x0
09 0x0
0a atikmdag
0b 0x0
0c 0x0
0d 0x0
0e 0x0

    Image path: \SystemRoot\system32\DRIVERS\atikmpag.sys
    Image name: atikmpag.sys
    Browse all global symbols  functions  data
    Timestamp:        Fri Feb 26 20:58:13 2016
```

So update the AMD driver, too.

I also see that you miss a lot of Updates, your Windows 7 is at Patchlevel from 2014 (`7601.18409.amd64fre.win7sp1_gdr.140303-2144`)

If you can't update, because Windows update gangs in an endless search, apply the [updates from my answer](https://superuser.com/a/996072/174557).

Comment: So i just have to update my Antivirus?Do I have to do anything else?

Comment: update first the Network card driver and next the Antivirus suite

Comment: it happened again. Heres the new one   https://ufile.io/5h9po

Comment: this time you have AMD graphic card issue

Comment: have you updated Windows and the 3 mentioned drivers?

Comment: Yes i did.I also moved the ram to another slot. Havent seen the Bsod yet.

Comment: ok, if it is answered and fixed, [mark my reply as answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235) to "close" the question.