# Stop windos from installing updates

Tags: windows-7, windows, windows-update

I am running Windows 7 Ultimate edition of a 64 bit machine. Though I have set the updates settings to not check for and install the updates, I find that when I am about to shut down my PC, a message comes saying that windows is installing the updates and do not turn off your PC.

Why is it happening? I manually powered off the system and then restarted it again. When I looked in the control panel update settings, it was set to not check and install updates. If it was set to not install updates, then why the Windows is downloading and installing updates?

Any help? I need to stop windows from installing any updates.

Comment: May be those updates were downloaded before you set not to download.

Comment: How did you stop it? Via gpedit?

Comment: Download the "windows update fixit tool" in this answer and run it in aggressive mode, reboot and reset windows update to your desired settings. settings..https://superuser.com/questions/951960/windows-7-sp1-windows-update-stuck-checking-for-updates/1022204#1022204

Comment: I highly encourage you to do research on the reasons you should keep Windows Update enabled.  WannaCrypt is one of many reasons to automatically install updates as they are released

Answer (score 2):

It is very likely, that the following is happening:

Windows tries to install updates it found earlier and requires a reboot. The update itself fails and at next boot, the same cycle happens over and over again.

Any change to windows update is for new updates, not updates that currently are pending.

If this is the case, there are two things you can do.

1. Fix the update problem in any way possible (manually installing the update, or actually fix the underlying problem by googling the error number)
2. Disable windows updates entirely by stopping and then disabling the "Windows Update (wuauserv)" service.

The 2nd one will definitely fix your problem, but it will also prevent you from doing anything with windows update until you change the settings for the service.

To do step 2, open a command prompt with administrative privileges, then type the following 2 commands:

```
sc stop wuauserv
sc config wuauserv start= disabled
```

If this is indeed the case, it is very likely, that once you fix the underlying problem, you no longer need or want to abandon windows update.

*If this is indeed a windows update failure, feel free to make a new post (not edit the current one) and tell us the error code.*

Comment: Disable windows updates entirely by stopping and then disabling the "Windows Update (wuauserv)" service. Could you please help me with this?

Comment: Type this command in admin CMD  `sc config wuauserv start= disabled` and restart PC.

Comment: @Snowbell updated the answer.