# unable to update new windows 7 install

Tags: windows-7, windows-update

I just did a factory restore on my old Lenovo ThinkPad W510 laptop that was running Windows 7 Ultimate 64-bit and now I'm unable to update it. When I go to the Updates dialog I see this:

[image]

I click the "Check for updates" button and...  nothing. I've let it sit for several days thinking that it'd just update on it's own and...  nothing.

Any ideas?

edit: this question is not a duplicate of [Windows 7 SP1 Windows Update stuck checking for updates](https://superuser.com/q/951960/172193) for the following reasons:

1. The symptoms are different as depicted in the screenshot. This isn't stuck on a "Checking for updates" screen as it's not even getting to that screen.
2. This Windows 7 did *not* have SP1 installed whereas the one in the alleged duplicate is.

If this question does get closed as being a duplicate I'll nominate to re-open and, failing that, seek clarification as to how exactly this is a duplicate in Meta.

Comment: What service pack is currently installed, or what is your current Windows 7 build number? Get this by running "winver".

Comment: @music2myear - Build 7600

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer. Avoid asking multiple distinct questions at once.

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://superuser.com/questions/951960/windows-7-sp1-windows-update-stuck-checking-for-updates

Comment: See my post here to fix this issue....https://superuser.com/questions/951960/windows-7-sp1-windows-update-stuck-checking-for-updates/1022204#1022204

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Windows 7 SP1 Windows Update stuck checking for updates](https://superuser.com/questions/951960/windows-7-sp1-windows-update-stuck-checking-for-updates)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Installing Service Pack 1 manually will likely resolve this issue.

You can download Windows 7 SP1 here: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=5842

Answer (score 2):

You should definitely install Service Pack 1 if it isn't already installed.  Additionally, you need to download and install these two updates manually:
[KB3020369](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=46817) and [KB3172605](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=53332) - in that order.  The second one will prompt you to reboot.  After you do that, you should be able to check for updates the usual way, and Windows will find and install them.