# Windows 7 x86 stuck on KB3092627 update

Tags: windows-7, windows-update

Trying to install Windows 7 x86 on old laptop Asus k50c.
It was installed successfully and I tried to install updates.

It stuck at update 148 of 183 kb3092627 and can't install it 3 days!

What should I do? Stop this update and launch it again or wait?

Comment: How to skip it? Should I stop installation and relaunch it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Windows 7 SP1 Windows Update stuck checking for updates](https://superuser.com/questions/951960/windows-7-sp1-windows-update-stuck-checking-for-updates)

Comment: Is it stuck at the checking for updates stage, downloading stage, or the installation stage of the updates?

Comment: installation stage

Answer (score 0):

Skip the kb to let other updates installed. After you clicking Check for update, uncheck the kb 3092627.
[image]

You can manually download the kb from windows update catalog:
https://www.catalog.update.microsoft.com/Search.aspx?q=KB3092627

And since the kb is replaced by kb 3125574, you can install kb 3125574 directly.