# Error 8024402C immediately after installing Windows from scratch and updating

Tags: windows-7, windows-update

I just installed Windows 7.1 (`SW_DVD5_Win_Pro_N_7w_SP1_32BIT_English_-2_MLF_X17-59635.ISO`) in a VirtualBox (Linux host) with a stable Internet connection.

Then I opened Windows Update, and let it install all of the updates it wanted, starting with a Windows Update update. It asked me to reboot, so I rebooted, and then opened Windows Update again, and it had a few more updates, then reboot again, etc, about 5~10 times.

**Problem**: Now it is showing me this:

[image]

I really only performed the steps above, I did not run any program except Windows Update, and in particular I installed no firewall or antivirus or anything.

What is the problem, and how to solve it?

Comment: Error code 8024402C: This error might be caused by a program running on your computer that's preventing Windows Update Services (SVCHOST) from accessing the Internet. Programs that might do this include firewalls, antispyware software, web accelerators, Internet security or antivirus programs and proxy servers.

Comment: @DavidPostill: Yes I saw that answers.microsoft.com forum thread, and that's why I wrote the before-last paragraph: "*I really only performed the steps above, I did not run any program except Windows Update, and in particular I installed no firewall or antivirus or anything.*"

Comment: Ah, but are you running a proxy somewhere in your network path?

Comment: @DavidPostill: No proxy, direct Internet from the host, not even a firewall.

Comment: I would use WSUSOffline in order to get your unpatched installation more current.  This is likely a case where the ISO is so out dated and your missing out on the major patches that address the Windows Update issues on Windows 7 your encountering this problem

Comment: 8024402C = WU_E_PT_WINHTTP_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED = Same as ERROR_WINHTTP_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED - the proxy server or target server name cannot be resolved. so you have Internet issues. Install the [Servicing Stack update and the July 2016 Update Rollup to fix slow Windows Update](https://superuser.com/a/996072/174557)

Comment: Of course, sounds just like MagicAndre's "magic" answer solution is just what you need actually.... BAM!!

Comment: @magicandre1981: Thanks! As described in the answer I posted based on your great tip, it worked well at first, but after installing the "2 important updates" of the above screenshot and rebooting, the same error appears again. I guess reinstalling the same update will not solve the problem again, right?

Comment: Manually install the [Convenience rollup update for Windows 7 SP1](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/3125574/convenience-rollup-update-for-windows-7-sp1-and-windows-server-2008-r2) and the [Rollup from May 2018](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4103718) and search again for updates.

Answer (score 0):

This procedure worked, huge thanks to magicandre1981:

1. Stop Windows Update service, for instance using the Service Manager (search for `services.msc` in the start menu).
2. Download and install KB3172605 ([32 Bit](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=53335) or [64 Bit](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=53332))
3. Reboot
4. Launch Windows Update and check for updates. The error should not appear and you should see something like this instead:

[image]

**Update**: Well, it worked well at first, but after installing the "*2 important updates*" of the above screenshot and rebooting, the same error appears again. Trying several times again, finally the update worked, and after rebooting/updating several times again I finally have a fully up-to-date Windows 7.1.

Comment: I marked it as duplicate, because it is both the same issue how to get WU working in Win7 and both time the same 2 updates fixes it.

Comment: @magicandre1981: So "X gets stuck" is the same question as "X returns Error 8024402C"? Do like you feel.

Comment: both are the same (how to get Windows Update on Windows 7 working). you see 2 different symptoms of the same issue (outdated Windows update client which fails to work)