# Windows 7 Clean Install, could not run Windows Update, Error Code 80072efe

Tags: windows, windows-7

Recently needed to reinstall the OS on my computer. After reinstalling the system (without installing any firewall or antivirus or any software at all), running windows update will fail and show this error code: 80072efe. Below is the log from WindowsUpdate.txt. What should I do to resolve this error?

```
Triggering AU detection through DetectNow API
2021-02-20  14:12:00:793     868    370 AU  Triggering Online detection (interactive)
2021-02-20  14:12:00:793     868    d9c AU  #############
2021-02-20  14:12:00:793     868    d9c AU  ## START ##  AU: Search for updates
2021-02-20  14:12:00:793     868    d9c AU  #########
2021-02-20  14:12:00:873     868    d9c AU  <<## SUBMITTED ## AU: Search for updates [CallId = {838D41FF-2318-482B-AFAE-0DB2586EBBE7}]
2021-02-20  14:12:00:873     868    e64 Agent   *************
2021-02-20  14:12:00:873     868    e64 Agent   ** START **  Agent: Finding updates [CallerId = AutomaticUpdates]
2021-02-20  14:12:00:873     868    e64 Agent   *********
2021-02-20  14:12:00:873     868    e64 Agent     * Online = Yes; Ignore download priority = No
2021-02-20  14:12:00:873     868    e64 Agent     * Criteria = "IsInstalled=0 and DeploymentAction='Installation' or IsPresent=1 and DeploymentAction='Uninstallation' or IsInstalled=1 and DeploymentAction='Installation' and RebootRequired=1 or IsInstalled=0 and DeploymentAction='Uninstallation' and RebootRequired=1"
2021-02-20  14:12:00:873     868    e64 Agent     * ServiceID = {9482F4B4-E343-43B6-B170-9A65BC822C77} Windows Update
2021-02-20  14:12:00:873     868    e64 Agent     * Search Scope = {Machine}
2021-02-20  14:12:00:873     868    e64 Setup   Checking for agent SelfUpdate
2021-02-20  14:12:00:873     868    e64 Setup   Client version: Core: 7.3.7600.16385  Aux: 7.3.7600.16385
2021-02-20  14:12:00:904     868    e64 Misc    Validating signature for C:\Windows\SoftwareDistribution\WuRedir\9482F4B4-E343-43B6-B170-9A65BC822C77\muv4wuredir.cab:
2021-02-20  14:12:00:951     868    e64 Misc     Microsoft signed: Yes
2021-02-20  14:12:00:997     868    e64 Misc    Validating signature for C:\Windows\SoftwareDistribution\WuRedir\9482F4B4-E343-43B6-B170-9A65BC822C77\muv4wuredir.cab:
2021-02-20  14:12:00:997     868    e64 Misc     Microsoft signed: Yes
2021-02-20  14:12:01:075     868    e64 Misc    WARNING: Send failed with hr = 80072efe.
2021-02-20  14:12:01:075     868    e64 Misc    WARNING: SendRequest failed with hr = 80072efe. Proxy List used: <(null)> Bypass List used : <(null)> Auth Schemes used : <>
2021-02-20  14:12:01:075     868    e64 Misc    WARNING: WinHttp: SendRequestUsingProxy failed for <https://www.update.microsoft.com/v11/3/legacy/windowsupdate/selfupdate/wuident.cab>. error 0x80072efe
2021-02-20  14:12:01:075     868    e64 Misc    WARNING: WinHttp: SendRequestToServerForFileInformation MakeRequest failed. error 0x80072efe
2021-02-20  14:12:01:075     868    e64 Misc    WARNING: WinHttp: SendRequestToServerForFileInformation failed with 0x80072efe
2021-02-20  14:12:01:075     868    e64 Misc    WARNING: WinHttp: ShouldFileBeDownloaded failed with 0x80072efe
2021-02-20  14:12:10:162     868    e64 Misc    WARNING: Send failed with hr = 80072efe.
2021-02-20  14:12:10:162     868    e64 Misc    WARNING: SendRequest failed with hr = 80072efe. Proxy List used: <(null)> Bypass List used : <(null)> Auth Schemes used : <>
2021-02-20  14:12:10:162     868    e64 Misc    WARNING: WinHttp: SendRequestUsingProxy failed for <https://www.update.microsoft.com/v11/3/legacy/windowsupdate/selfupdate/wuident.cab>. error 0x80072efe
2021-02-20  14:12:10:162     868    e64 Misc    WARNING: WinHttp: SendRequestToServerForFileInformation MakeRequest failed. error 0x80072efe
2021-02-20  14:12:10:162     868    e64 Misc    WARNING: WinHttp: SendRequestToServerForFileInformation failed with 0x80072efe
2021-02-20  14:12:10:162     868    e64 Misc    WARNING: WinHttp: ShouldFileBeDownloaded failed with 0x80072efe
2021-02-20  14:12:10:225     868    e64 Misc    WARNING: Send failed with hr = 80072efe.
2021-02-20  14:12:10:225     868    e64 Misc    WARNING: SendRequest failed with hr = 80072efe. Proxy List used: <(null)> Bypass List used : <(null)> Auth Schemes used : <>
2021-02-20  14:12:10:225     868    e64 Misc    WARNING: WinHttp: SendRequestUsingProxy failed for <https://www.update.microsoft.com/v11/3/legacy/windowsupdate/selfupdate/wuident.cab>. error 0x80072efe
2021-02-20  14:12:10:225     868    e64 Misc    WARNING: WinHttp: SendRequestToServerForFileInformation MakeRequest failed. error 0x80072efe
2021-02-20  14:12:10:225     868    e64 Misc    WARNING: WinHttp: SendRequestToServerForFileInformation failed with 0x80072efe
2021-02-20  14:12:10:225     868    e64 Misc    WARNING: WinHttp: ShouldFileBeDownloaded failed with 0x80072efe
2021-02-20  14:12:10:303     868    e64 Misc    WARNING: Send failed with hr = 80072efe.
2021-02-20  14:12:10:303     868    e64 Misc    WARNING: SendRequest failed with hr = 80072efe. Proxy List used: <(null)> Bypass List used : <(null)> Auth Schemes used : <>
2021-02-20  14:12:10:303     868    e64 Misc    WARNING: WinHttp: SendRequestUsingProxy failed for <https://www.update.microsoft.com/v11/3/legacy/windowsupdate/selfupdate/wuident.cab>. error 0x80072efe
2021-02-20  14:12:10:303     868    e64 Misc    WARNING: WinHttp: SendRequestToServerForFileInformation MakeRequest failed. error 0x80072efe
2021-02-20  14:12:10:303     868    e64 Misc    WARNING: WinHttp: SendRequestToServerForFileInformation failed with 0x80072efe
2021-02-20  14:12:10:303     868    e64 Misc    WARNING: WinHttp: ShouldFileBeDownloaded failed with 0x80072efe
2021-02-20  14:12:10:303     868    e64 Misc    WARNING: DownloadFileInternal failed for https://www.update.microsoft.com/v11/3/legacy/windowsupdate/selfupdate/wuident.cab: error 0x80072efe
2021-02-20  14:12:10:303     868    e64 Setup   WARNING: SelfUpdate check failed to download package information, error = 0x80072EFE
2021-02-20  14:12:10:303     868    e64 Setup   FATAL: SelfUpdate check failed, err = 0x80072EFE
2021-02-20  14:12:10:303     868    e64 Agent     * WARNING: Skipping scan, self-update check returned 0x80072EFE
2021-02-20  14:12:10:398     868    e64 Agent     * WARNING: Exit code = 0x80072EFE
2021-02-20  14:12:10:398     868    e64 Agent   *********
2021-02-20  14:12:10:398     868    e64 Agent   **  END  **  Agent: Finding updates [CallerId = AutomaticUpdates]
2021-02-20  14:12:10:398     868    e64 Agent   *************
2021-02-20  14:12:10:398     868    e64 Agent   WARNING: WU client failed Searching for update with error 0x80072efe
2021-02-20  14:12:10:398     868    ecc AU  >>##  RESUMED  ## AU: Search for updates [CallId = {838D41FF-2318-482B-AFAE-0DB2586EBBE7}]
2021-02-20  14:12:10:398     868    ecc AU    # WARNING: Search callback failed, result = 0x80072EFE
2021-02-20  14:12:10:398     868    ecc AU    # WARNING: Failed to find updates with error code 80072EFE
2021-02-20  14:12:10:398     868    ecc AU  #########
2021-02-20  14:12:10:398     868    ecc AU  ##  END  ##  AU: Search for updates [CallId = {838D41FF-2318-482B-AFAE-0DB2586EBBE7}]
2021-02-20  14:12:10:398     868    ecc AU  #############
2021-02-20  14:12:10:398     868    ecc AU  Successfully wrote event for AU health state:0
2021-02-20  14:12:10:398     868    ecc AU  Successfully wrote event for AU health state:0
2021-02-20  14:12:10:414     868    e64 Report  CWERReporter finishing event handling. (00000000)
2021-02-20  14:12:15:362     868    e64 Report  REPORT EVENT: {5D7E261C-039A-442F-8F4F-891EF7AA740E}    2021-02-20 14:12:10:303-0600    1   148 101 {D67661EB-2423-451D-BF5D-13199E37DF28}  1   80072efe    SelfUpdate  Failure Software Synchronization    Windows Update Client failed to detect with error 0x80072efe.
2021-02-20  14:12:15:362     868    e64 Report  CWERReporter::HandleEvents - WER report upload completed with status 0x8
2021-02-20  14:12:15:362     868    e64 Report  WER Report sent: 7.3.7600.16385 0x80072efe D67661EB-2423-451D-BF5D-13199E37DF28 Scan 101 Unmanaged
2021-02-20  14:12:15:362     868    e64 Report  CWERReporter finishing event handling. (00000000)
```

Comment: After you get the windows update client installed, see this page>>>>https://superuser.com/questions/951960/windows-7-sp1-windows-update-stuck-checking-for-updates/1022204#1022204

Comment: I have used Belarc Advisory, it will tell you which updates to find and install. Very handy, to me anyway. I am on Windows 7 SP1 now.

Comment: See More Information section to download the latest agent, right click in the link and select "save link as">>>https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/information-for-network-administrators-about-how-to-obtain-the-latest-windows-update-agent-c1ebc7ca-27c3-e6b0-5da9-a1c6ffe12e82

Comment: Did you install "Windows 7" or "Windows 7 SP1"? This makes a lot of difference for troubleshooting and answering tour question.

Answer (score 3):

The error code 0x80072EFE occurs after a new installation because the Windows Update Client is not up to date.

You can download and install the latest version from the following page:

[Update Windows Update Agent to latest version - Windows Client | Microsoft Docs](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/windows-client/deployment/update-windows-update-agent)

But as with everyone else, I can only recommend you switch to Win 10.

Comment: Better link to the latest update agent, see more information section for links>>>https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/information-for-network-administrators-about-how-to-obtain-the-latest-windows-update-agent-c1ebc7ca-27c3-e6b0-5da9-a1c6ffe12e82

Answer (score 0):

Windows 7 is fully over and gone. Not even security updates anymore.

All you can do, if you need it, is download and install SP1. Microsoft still has that.

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/install-windows-7-service-pack-1-sp1-b3da2c0f-cdb6-0572-8596-bab972897f61

If your machine is strong enough (older Windows 7 machines may not be), upgrade it to Windows 7. Still free as far as I know.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this problem after installing Windows 7 with Service Pack one.  With some research I found that two updates that were required to move forward caused the problem and that if you download them from the Microsoft Catalog site you can then start getting the rest of the updates the regular way.  The problem is that you cannot go to the Catalog site with IE, so you have to install another browser.  It was easiest to install FireFox as you also can not use more modern installers.

The Updates are KB3020329 & KB3125574

I made a video on this and posted it on Youtube.
https://youtu.be/9y4XeCNYnig