# Windows 7 too many errors after installtion

Tags: windows, windows-7, powershell, java

- everytime i install windows 7 i got those error massages

1. in windows updater i got error `code 80072EFE`

- i searched and found that it's can be solved with `kb3138612` but it's
  alert me `The Update Isn't applicatable to your computer`

2. in vc_redist 2015 when trying to install it it's give me this error
   `0x80240017 - Unspecified error`
3. in java installtion and xampp it's alert that
   `api-ms-win-crt-runtime-l1-1-0.dll` is missing and some other dll files
   is missing
4. in powershell when trying to install [scoop](https://scoop.sh/)
   it's show me this error

```
The term 'iwr' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program
g of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:4
+ iwr <<<<  -useb get.scoop.sh | iex
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (iwr:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

- i don't know why all of those errors and i know that windows 7 is
  deprecated but i used to work on it so i hope someone help me to
  solve all of those errors

Comment: I am not sure if updates are available any more (Windows security essentials excepted). Did you download SP1 manually and install it?  What stops you from upgrading to Windows 10?

Comment: My pc capabilities are weak for example ram is `2GB` and windows 10 make my pc slower so i'm using windows 7 32bit on it

Comment: and also i like windows 7 so if i have better pc i will also work on win7

Comment: It appears most of your errors required some additional research: For instance, [api-ms-win-crt-runtime-l1-1-0.dll](https://superuser.com/questions/986496/missing-api-ms-win-crt-runtime-1-1-0-dll), is well documented.  The Scoop errors are due to the fact you don't have PowerShell 5.1 installed more than likely and/or .NET Framework 4.5 installed. [80072EFE - Solution](https://superuser.com/questions/1627689/windows-7-clean-install-could-not-run-windows-update-error-code-80072efe).  Everything I have mentioned required Windows 7 SP1 to be installed.

Comment: @Ramhound thank you they are solved and i will check powershell problem in scoop docs

Comment: See my answer here>>>>https://superuser.com/questions/951960/windows-7-sp1-windows-update-stuck-checking-for-updates/1022204#1022204